# Operator does not exist: interval > integer

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that works on Postgresql 7.4 but not on Postgresql 8.3 with same database.

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM login_session WHERE (now()-modified) > timeout;
```

Gets the following error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: interval > integer
LINE 1: ...ELECT * FROM login_session WHERE (now()-modified) > timeout ...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Column `modified` is a `timestamp` and `timeout` is an `integer`.

Is there some settings I need to change on server?

I'm installing an application for a client on new server (ubuntu) so I can't change queries in the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create or replace function int2interval (x integer) returns interval as $$ select $1*'1 sec'::interval $$ language sql;
create cast (integer as interval) with function int2interval (integer) as implicit;
```

ought to do it.

Comment: This is preferential to the pgsql version, since it doesn't require pgsql. I also ran timings of the 'multiply vs 1 sec cast' vs 'concatenate to a string and cast'. This version (the 1 sec cast) is ~ 30% faster

Answer (score 13):

There are a lot of changes between 7.4 and 8.3. Some of the most drastic were the removal of some automatic casts.

I suppose the "timeout" is in seconds? If so you could change the query to:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    login_session
WHERE
    (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - modified) > (timeout * '1 sec'::interval);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION intToInterval(arg integer)
  RETURNS interval AS
$BODY$
   BEGIN      
      return CAST( arg || ' seconds' AS interval ); 
   END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE CAST (integer AS interval)
WITH FUNCTION intToInterval ( integer )
AS IMPLICIT;
```

(Assuming timeout is measured in seconds - change accordingly otherwise)